# Combining Multiple Codebases into one...Is creating a component for each codebase the right way?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am beginning a project where I am tasked with combining 7 codebases into 1 codebase. Each of these codebases are very different and handle different functions (Registration, Surveys, Email Blaster, etc). I would like to use Vue for the frontend of each of these (Laravel on the backend).

My initial structure for this project involves using one app.js file with one Vue instance and separating each of the codebases into components. Vue-Router will determine which one of the components gets loaded.

```
//example of the layout thusfar
let routes = [
{ path: '/registration', component: require('./components/admin/Registration.vue').default },
{ path: '/surveys', component: require('./components/admin/Surveys.vue').default }
]
```

Should I be using a separate Vue app for each codebase or will I be fine by splitting them up as components in the same Vue app? They will all be pulling from the same database, using the same API calls, and be housed under the same domain (registration.example.com, surveys.example.com, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poor showing here by SO. The answer is to separate each codebase into different apps for those who see this. Otherwise, managing astronomically large components will be difficult. Don't listen to Ram.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is but it decreases the performance. You can explore vuex. Vuex is a state management pattern + library for Vue.js applications. It serves as a centralized store for all the components in an application, with rules ensuring that the state can only be mutated in a predictable fashion.

Its easy to learn and wont take much time as well.